# BackgroundWorker In Form.Load event

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, sql-server-ce, backgroundworker

I'm working in a c# windows application with vs2010 and a local database.In one of my forms i use a BindingNavigator with a group of textboxes filled by the database and a ReporViewer. I've added a background worker in order to fill the table adapters in case there are a lot of records in the database.

The problem is that the way I'm using the background worker when i debug my app i cannot see any data in the textboxes, otherwise when i run my app it's working fine. I know that this is a case of accessing the UI on a non-UI thread and it is wrong. Is there a another way around it?Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void Client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); 
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Client);
    this.projectTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Project);

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an exception in the Debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, a background worker returns on the same thread, and would actually throw an exception about the non-UI thread. However, this might be eaten in your case. You should be using the `RunWorkerCompleted` event for items that are to happen after your main work is done, especially when looking to update the UI. And, this *should* return to the same thread it was called from (UI in your case) as mentioned above.

So, I would move your UI processing code (`RefreshReport`) into a new method set up for the RunWorkerCompleted.

However, my suggestion would be to take a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). It ends up making code much cleaner and easier to debug IMO.

Example (rough and may not compile due to the nulls, but you can get the jist :)):

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{//Do Async Stuff});
task.ContinueWith((previousTask)=>{//Do your UI Stuff}, null, null, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
//The FromCurrentSync makes sure the method returns 
//to the same thread (UI in this case) that it started
```

I know that is not a direct answer, but more of a suggestion towards what I would consider a cleaner, more debuggable approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i'm relatively new to this stuff so i would need a more direct answer. My question is, can i use tableadapter.Fill() in the backgroundWorker_DoWork event? Is the above code correct?

Comment: I used something like this but can't yet figure it out:               public Task FillAync()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {               this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Client);           this.projectTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Project);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            });
        }

Comment: Now that I look at it further, no. I will update my answer for your specific scenario. However, I would still HIGHLY suggest looking into the TPL, especially if you are new. Why use older technology to start?

Comment: Thank you very much in advance, i also tried something like this and it seems to work. Can you tell me if i'm correct?        

private void Client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 FillAync();
}

public Task FillAync()
{
        
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{


this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Client);
this.projectTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Project);

if (InvokeRequired)
{
 this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport));
 return; 
}
});
}

Comment: If it works, then that is a start, however please see my updated answer. You should not have to invoke if you use RunWorkerCompleted (in your old code), or if you use ContinueWith for your new code....the new code would go something like:  var task = FillAync(); task.ContinueWith((prevTask)=>{reportViewer1.RefreshReport();}, new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);             But, again, if it works, that is the first step. Please do remember appreciation is shown in upvotes and accepted answers (checkmark next to answer).

Comment: Thank you!!! Both codes Old and New is great. I found a little different way though based more on your first answer.It is working but just to make sure:                                                                    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Client));
            task1.ContinueWith(delegate { this.projectTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Project); }).ContinueWith((prevTask) => { reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); }, new CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Comment: Looks fine to me. Except you are missing a closing paren in the StartNew, but I think that is a copy paste thing :) Glad to help